# Get address and city name of a LatLng point using GoogleGeocoding Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to get address and city name of a LatLng point using [google_geocoding](https://pub.dev/packages/google_geocoding):

```
var googleGeocoding =
    GoogleGeocoding("MY_KEY");
var result = await googleGeocoding.geocoding.getReverse(LatLon(lat, lng));
print(result?.results?.first.formattedAddress.toString());
```

The result of the print:

```
Corso Italia, 22-24, 20122 Milano MI, Italy
```

I need to get only `Corso Italia`, the string before the comma and `Milano`, how can I get that?

I tried to use `addressComponents`, but I only got numbers (especially if I select locations in countries like Italy)

```
print(result?.results?.first.addressComponents?.first.longName.toString());
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `addressComponents` instead of `formattedAddress`?

Comment: @PeterKoltai thanks, I updated the question

Comment: Add a breakpoint and check what's inside `result?.results?.first.addressComponents`. Since you added `first` as well, I think you print out only the first address component, and you need some other, not the first. Address components should have a type or something, you can find out which do you need if you are able to inspect it.

Comment: @PeterKoltai not it works thanks!

Comment: Good to hear, you are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

It may not be the most optimal but you could play with picking the string through the spaces and then make the string in such a way that you can have the sequence you want